# Sorting Arrays of Arrays by useing date in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

```
$data = array( 
    array("firstname" => "Mary", "age" => 25,"date" => '14/07/2014 04:50'), 
    array("firstname" => "Amanda","age" => 18 ,"date" => '14/07/2014 13:20'), 
    array("firstname" => "James", "age" => 31 ,"date" => '10/07/2014 03:00'), 
    array("firstname" => "Patricia","age" => 7 ,"date" => '09/07/2010 06:32'), 
    array("firstname" => "Michael", "age" => 43 ,"date" => '10/01/2010 04:50'), 
    array("firstname" => "Ranga","age" => 23,"date"=> '08/06/1990 03:52' ),
    array("firstname" => "Sarah","age" => 24 ,"date" => '08/06/1991 04:25'), 
    array("firstname" => "Patrick","age" => 27 ,"date" => '19/07/2002 04:50'),
);

function compare_date($a, $b) { 
    return strnatcmp($a['date'], $b['date']); 
} 

usort($data, 'compare_date');

print_r($data);
```

It's not working. Please help.

Comment: You don't explain how it fails to work but it's fairly obvious that alphabetic order is not interesting for dates. Can't you simply use actual dates (either timestamps or DateTime objects)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare them by as dates, not natural order

```
function compare_date($a, $b) {
    return (strtotime(str_replace('/', '.', $a['date'])) < strtotime(str_replace('/', '.',   $b['date']))) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

`14/07/2014 04:50` assumes 14 is the day and 7 is the month. But `strtotime` will see them the other way around. I am replacing / with . so

14/07/2014 04:50 becomes 14.07.2014 04:50

14.07.2014 04:50 will be interpreted properly by strtotime

Answer (score 2):

Use a couple of [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects to compare the two values. You can create these objects using the [`DateTime::createFromFormat`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) method:

```
function compare_date($a, $b) { 
    return DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y H:i",$a['date']) > DateTime::createFromFormat("d/m/Y H:i",$b['date']); 
}
```

Comment: using `DateTime` is more elegant than my replacing / with .

Answer (score 0):

you should use dates in `yyyy-mm-dd H:i:s` format, for example, '2014-05-03 13:09:01'

when you compare two strings, it compares in natural order http://php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcmp.php. 
Consider this two dates `14/07/2014 04:50` and `20/07/2013 04:50`,

if you compare like that, second one will be bigger, but as you can see the first one is bigger, because of the year `2014`

**edit:** convert it to the necessary format during compare, like

```
date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime('20/07/2013 04:50'))
```

Comment: @Ranga - That's what your current code does and you've said "it doesn't work".